# Port a SUMPRODUCT slide rate commission calculation from Excel to MYSQL

Tags: mysql, excel

I have a sliding commission rate calculation in excel / googlesheet I am trying to port to MYSQL/PHP

I have this table in range B3:E9 (excel/google sheets)

```
+---+----------+-----------+-----------+----------+
| A |    B     |     C     |     D     |    E     |
+---+----------+-----------+-----------+----------+
| 3 | Tier Min | Tier Max  | Com. Rate | Dif Rate |
| 4 | 0        | 50,000    | 10.00%    | 0.10     |
| 5 | 50,000   | 100,000   | 15.00%    | 0.05     |
| 6 | 100,000  | 200,000   | 20.00%    | 0.05     |
| 7 | 200,000  | 300,000   | 25.00%    | 0.05     |
| 8 | 300,000  | 500,000   | 30.00%    | 0.05     |
| 9 | 500,000  | 1,000,000 | 35.00%    | 0.05     |
+---+----------+-----------+-----------+----------+

+----------------+----------------+
|      Sales     |  $ 160,000.00  |
+----------------+----------------+
| Commission US$ |  $ 24,500.00   |
| Global Rate %  | 15.31%         |
+----------------+----------------+
```

I input "Sales" amount in H4 and I have the formula to calculate the Commission US$:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(H4>$B$4:$B$9),--(H4-$B$4:$B$9),$E$4:$E$9)
```

Now my question. If I have One table called "Sales"

```
+----+------------+--------------+
| ID | Date_Sales | Sales_Amount |
+----+------------+--------------+
|  1 | 2015-01-31 |       160000 |
|  2 | 2015-02-28 |       142000 |
|  3 | 2015-03-31 |       430222 |
|  4 | 2015-04-30 |       234000 |
+----+------------+--------------+
```

And another "commission table" (structure to define), which reflects my tier rate table above (0-50 000, 10%, etc...)

What would be the best way in mySQL (combined with php if necessary) to calculate the correct commission for January 2015, which should amount to $24 500?

Thanks in advance for your help and suggestions.

Comment: I thought I understood `--`, but what does `--(H4-$B$4:$B$9)` do?

Comment: I think it's just saying "substract whichever value in this array happens to be in the same row as this formula". Is that right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you're after something like this:

```
SELECT s.id
     , SUM((s.sales_amount - r.tier_min) * r.dif_rate) x 
  FROM sales s 
  JOIN commission_rates r 
    ON r.tier_min <= s.sales_amount 
 GROUP 
    BY s.id;
+----+----------+
| id | x        |
+----+----------+
|  1 | 24500.00 |
|  2 | 20900.00 |
|  3 | 96566.60 |
|  4 | 41000.00 |
+----+----------+
```

Comment: great solution. Congrats and Thanks, Strawberry!

Comment: Hello Strawberry, I have another Mysql select problem I would like to share with you. Would be great if you could halp me on this! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39326820/select-to-calculate-sales-average-by-customer-taking-first-sales-into-account-my